# How to download XHR files from chromedriver using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As shown in the screenshot, I need to download all the XHR files in the network when any call made using python?[image: xhr files screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First load an URL on the domain you're targeting a file download from. This allows you to perform an AJAX request on that domain, without running into cross site scripting issues.

Next,  inject some javascript into the DOM which fires off an AJAX request. Once the AJAX request returns a response, take the response and load it into a FileReader object. From there you can extract the base64 encoded content of the file by calling readAsDataUrl().  Then take the base64 encoded content and appending it to window, a gobally accessible variable.

Finally, because the AJAX request is asynchronous, enter a Python while loop waiting for the content to be appended to the window. Once it's appended,  decode the base64 content retrieved from the window and save it to a file.

This solution should work across all modern browsers supported by Selenium, and works whether text or binary, and across all mime types.